# Does $\mathcal{N}=1$ SCFTs have geometric constructions?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, string-theory, supersymmetry, algebraic-geometry

There are class S theories which are 4d $\mathcal{N}=2$ SCFTs by compactifying 6d $\mathcal{N}=(2,0)$ SCFT on a Riemann surface.

Does similar geometric constructions exist for 4d $\mathcal{N}=1$ SCFTs? Is it simply given by some similar compactification of $\mathcal{N}=(2,0)$ SCFT on a Riemann surface but only preserving $\mathcal{N}=1$ supersymmetry?

Comment: Yes... https://arxiv.org/abs/1610.09178 is one of the main papers about this.

Comment: Thank you, your quick answer is right on the point!

Comment: Perhaps I should have done some reference checks beforehand... if that's the case, sorry about that.

Comment: And to add to Conor's answer, there's also this https://arxiv.org/abs/1203.0303